# Why does Clang not like boost::transform_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, clang

With Clang 8.0.1 and Boost 1.70, the following program

```cpp
// transform.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

struct Foo
{
    int x;
};

struct XGetter
{
    auto operator()(const Foo& foo) const noexcept { return foo.x; }
};

int main()
{
    const std::vector<Foo> foos {{1}, {2}, {3}};
    using boost::make_transform_iterator;
    const auto first = make_transform_iterator(foos.cbegin(), XGetter {});
    const auto last = make_transform_iterator(foos.cend(), XGetter {});
    std::cout << *std::max_element(first, last) << std::endl;
}
```

fails to compile

```sh
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -o transform transform.cpp

/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.1/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2494:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement
      '__is_forward_iterator<boost::iterators::transform_iterator<XGetter, std::__1::__wrap_iter<const Foo *>,
      boost::use_default, boost::use_default> >::value' "std::max_element requires a ForwardIterator"
    static_assert(__is_forward_iterator<_ForwardIterator>::value,
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.1/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2512:19: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::max_element<boost::iterators::transform_iterator<XGetter, std::__1::__wrap_iter<const
      Foo *>, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>, std::__1::__less<int, int> >' requested here
    return _VSTD::max_element(__first, __last,
                  ^
transform.cpp:24:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::max_element<boost::iterators::transform_iterator<XGetter, std::__1::__wrap_iter<const Foo *>,
      boost::use_default, boost::use_default> >' requested here
    std::cout << *std::max_element(first, last) << std::endl;
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

I was under the impression that [boost::transform_iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html) inherited the iterator category of iterator it models. What is going wrong?

Comment: [Works](https://godbolt.org/z/KIFjNp) in Clang 8.0.0 and Boost 1.70.0

Comment: You say `transform.cpp` but then `transform_itr.cpp`, and your `max_element` call is not on line 23 - can we have a real [mcve] please?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just shortened the file name to make the example more succinct - doesn't change the validity.

Comment: Additional info: macOS Mojava 10.14.6. Both LLVM and Boost installed with Homebrew.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah, and the off-by-one line number is as I added "transform.cpp" to the example for clarity, recompiled and updated with this in the real code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not reproducible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The (pre-C++20) standard requires forward-or-stronger iterators:

- to produce a real reference when dereferenced;
- to produce references to the same object when two equal iterators are dereferenced (i.e., no stashing)

Since your transformation returns by value, there's no way for `transform_iterator` to meet both requirements. Thus, it can only advertise itself as an input iterator.

The fix is to change `XGetter` to return by reference, or to use `std::mem_fn(&Foo::x)` which does that for you.

Comment: Interesting! So does this mean that all the compiler versions that are allowing this to compile are non-compliant?

Comment: No. The implementation has no obligation to check that you actually passed a forward iterator to `max_element`.

Comment: Blimey, that's subtle.